# Could we encourage post-answer engagement/feedback from askers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Not sure how to properly word that for a title, but essentially, what I mean is quite often we get people who come here, ask a question, receive answers (in some cases even accepting one) and then disappear.

In some cases, this is fine, but sometimes it would be helpful to know if the answers actually helped the user in question.

For example, if someone asked for a clarification on how to answer certain questions on the form for UK visit visas, and got an answer, it could be helpful to know if it worked out for them in the end.

Perhaps the powers that be could implement a system that sends an email out to users periodically reminding them to chose an answer (at the least) and maybe even to leave feedback on how helpful/accurate the advice actually was.

Answer (score 2):

People come to TSE to ask a visa type of question and then disappear. Sometimes they show up weeks or months later, sometimes not.  Sometimes they take the question to another site and I have seen it happen enough times to believe it's standard OP behaviour.

Sometimes the OP shotguns their question into a dozen sites and loses track of where they are. They show up the next day and ask the same question because they didn't keep notes of where they asked. Visa questions are always **EMOTIVE** and do not have the same trajectory as someone asking (for example) how to reach the base camp at Mount Everest.

The abandon rate in TSE is appalling. I don't know how many answers get the 'acceptance' check mark, but I bet it's the lowest in the whole SO framework.

The TSE ecosystem rewards good answers by community votes and that's that.  OP abandonment behaviour is part of **WHAT IS** and I don't see any sort of software mechanism changing it.

> In some cases, this is fine, but sometimes it would be helpful to know
>   if the answers actually helped the user in question.

It may seem presumptive, but we already know it worked out OK. Or it would have worked out OK if they actually used the answer.

> For example, if someone asked for a clarification on how to answer
>   certain questions on the form for UK visit visas, and got an answer,
>   it could be helpful to know if it worked out for them in the end.

Again, you have to trust that they got good info. Whether they used it or not or whether another site gave a different answer they liked more or whether the OP decided not to fill out the form at all... All of those things are irrelevant. We did the best we could, the community voted, and end of story.

> Perhaps the powers that be could implement a system that sends an
>   email out to users periodically reminding them to chose an answer (at
>   the least) and maybe even to leave feedback on how helpful/accurate
>   the advice actually was.

I respectfully disagree. We are not Amazon sending out follow-up emails every two seconds.  Visa questions are **EMOTIVE** and personal; postmortems are unnecessarily intrusive.

On the other side, we should be a whole lot more aggressive in marking duplicates.

Comment: The acceptance rate for visas is indeed on the low side. The median acceptance rate is 27%, but for visas it's 22%: https://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/630384/accepted-rate-per-tag. It is even lower for visa-refusals (20%).

Comment: For comparison, on Stackoverflow the median acceptance rate is 35%: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/630385/accepted-rate-per-tag

Comment: @pnuts, no I specifically checked out the *median* value :) However it's calculated for tags with at least 100 answers (1000 for Stackoverflow) so outliers are not included.

Comment: @pnuts my goal was to show that Gayot was right and our acceptance rates are indeed lower than site average, especially for visa questions, and I think that point stands. Whatever is the precise acceptance rate is not important.

Comment: The acceptance rate from OP's is toilet. That's it and all about it.

Answer (score 1):

If necessary you can always ping the person who asked the question (by posting a comment on their post). If they're still active anywhere on the StackExchange community they will come back and give an answer.

Otherwise I don't think it's necessary to implement an 'email ping' functionality - it would mostly be useful to Travel.SE and Expats.SE, so the usefulness is of limited scope.